# Execute JavaScript on node creation of a specific content type

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7

I would like to execute a JavaScript function only on node creation and node edit of one specific content type. It is only one small function call.

Let's call the Drupal 7 content type "`tear`", and the JavaScript function "`doitnow();`"

Any ideas how to do this?

Thank you very much.

Nils

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create your own module and implement [hook_node_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7), [hook_node_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) and [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) and take the appropriate steps. You also have to create some JavaScript codes with [Drupal behavior](http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors), and you're ready. You have to use a temporary session variable after node creation/update, because this way you can check the existance of this variable in hook_node_view, and add the JS setting which "tells" a new "tear" content has been added.

#### [You can download the whole module here.](http://www.mediafire.com/?o7pa0a6cbg0tgze)

You have to put this module to the `sites/all/modules/testModule` directory.

OK, here's the code of the module:

### `testModule.info`:

```
name = Test Customization Module
description = Customizing stuffs on the site...
core = 7.x
package = My modules

scripts[] = js/testModule.behaviors.js
```

### `testModule.module`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert()
 * 
 * @see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7
 * @param object $node 
 */
function testModule_node_insert($node) {    
    switch ($node->type) {
        case 'tear':
            $_SESSION['tear_just_inserted'] = microtime();
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_update()
 * 
 * @see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7
 * @param object $node 
 */
function testModule_node_update($node) {
    switch ($node->type) {
        case 'tear':
            $_SESSION['tear_just_inserted'] = microtime();
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function testModule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    switch ($node->type) {
        case 'tear':
            // we call doitnow() if it's needed (if "tear" content was added before)
            if (isset($_SESSION['tear_just_inserted'])) {
                drupal_add_js(array('testModule' => array('tear_just_added' => TRUE)), 'setting');
                unset($_SESSION['tear_just_inserted']);
            }

            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_overlay_child_initialize()
 * @see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!overlay!overlay.api.php/function/hook_overlay_child_initialize/7
 */
function testModule_overlay_child_initialize() {
    // Add our custom JavaScript: we don't want the node/add/tear to appear on the overlay, because this way the JS setting doesn't get added properly
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'testModule') . '/js/testModule.overlay.behaviors.js');
}
```

### `js/testModule.behaviors.js`:

```
(function ($) {   
    Drupal.behaviors.testModule = {
        doitnow: function(){
            alert("A new \"tear\" content has just been added!");
        },

        attach: function (context, settings) {
            try{
                if(settings.testModule.tear_just_added){
                    this.doitnow();
                }
            } catch(ex){}
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

### `js/testModule.overlay.behaviors.js`:

```
(function ($) {
    // Disable overlay for creating the "tear" node.
    Drupal.behaviors.testModule = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            var $tear_link = $('a[href*="node/add/tear"]'),
            tear_link_href = $tear_link.attr('href');
            if( $tear_link.length > 0 ) {
                // we want to avoid opening the content adding for "tear" content type in the overlay
                // so we open it in the current window
                $tear_link.unbind();
                $tear_link.click(function(e){
                    window.open(tear_link_href,'_self',false);
                    e.stopPropagation();
                })
            }    
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Ask if something isn't quite clear.

Comment: +1. Didn't know the overlay stuff. Pretty straight forward and geeky.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter, thank you so much! Works perfectly. Only when i add the following into the doitnow function it does not work any more: FB.api(
        '/me/shareatear:share',
        'post',
        { tear: document.URL },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('done. ' + response.id);
           }
        });

Comment: does it have something to do with Namespaces?

Comment: @Nils: You're welcome, glad I could help. Please open a developer panel in your browser with `Ctrl+Shift+I` (or `F12` in Chrome), and click on the `Console` tab. What kind of error message is on this panel when `doitnow()` is getting called? Maybe this way we could debug the JS error.

Comment: @AyeshKarunaratne: thanks, and you can also implement [hook_overlay_parent_initialize()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21overlay%21overlay.api.php/function/hook_overlay_parent_initialize/7), and add some codes there.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter, the error is simply that the called function FB.api() is unknwon. See the other topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863207/call-global-js-function-from-module-js-file-in-drupal-7