# Call global JS function from module .js file in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7

With the [great help of Sk8erPeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856769/execute-javascript-on-node-creation-of-a-specific-content-type) I managed to execute Javascript code on node creation and node update of a certain content type in Drupal 7.

My problem now is that I can not call the function FB.api from withing this modules js files. Does it have something to do with Javascript namespaces? Running the FB.api() function from console works fine...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Nils

Comment: Hi Nils! I also asked it in the other topic, but are there any error messages when calling this function from your code in the `Console` tab of the developer tool (like Chrome's built-in stuff or Firebug)? :) Or what is the symptom of the "error"? Can you show us the whole code where you are calling this function?

Comment: @Sk8erPeter, just calling doitnow() with your example alert works perfectly without any errors. What does not work is calling another function from another module called FB.api(). I can run this Fb.api function from console without any error. But inside the doitnow() function it seems to be unknown. The according error in the console is "FB is not defined @ http://www.share-a-tear.com/sites/all/modules/testModule/js/testModule.behaviors.js?m4zq9p:1".

Comment: this is the function i actually want to call inside doitnow():  
    FB.api(
        '/me/shareatear:share',
        'post',
        { tear: document.URL },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('worked. ' + response.id);
           }
        });

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments... I'm just watching your [`testModule.behaviors.js`](http://www.share-a-tear.com/sites/all/modules/testModule/js/testModule.behaviors.js), and it doesn't even look similar to the function that I wrote to you [here in the other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10858345/517705).

Your current code is only like this:

```
FB.api(
    '/me/shareatear:share',
    'post',
    { tear: document.URL },
    function(response) {
       if (!response || response.error) {
          alert('Error occured');
       } else {
          alert('done. ' + response.id);
       }
    });
```

Where is `Drupal.behaviors`, and its `attach` function I showed you earlier? Where are all the other stuffs? :)
It's not even surprising that the current code outputs an error, because I think this JavaScript file is included **before** even defining the `FB` object, and this way you call this code directly **in the header**.

I think your `testModule.behaviors.js` file should look like this (based on the previous code we were talking about):

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.testModule = {
        doitnow: function () {
            alert("A new \"tear\" content has just been added!");

            // change this code to the appropriate one
            FB.api('/me/shareatear:share', 'post', {
                tear: document.URL
            }, function (response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert('Error occured');
                } else {
                    alert('done. ' + response.id);
                }
            });

        },

        attach: function (context, settings) {
            try {
                if (settings.testModule.tear_just_added) {
                    this.doitnow();
                }
            } catch (ex) {}
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

So REPLACE your CURRENT content (where you are only calling `FB.api` without any [Drupal-specific behaviors](http://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors) "wrappers"), and change its content to this one.

---

EDIT:

OK, try to set the weight of this module higher ONCE with the following `db_query()`, so its hooks get invoked later than the other modules' hooks. After putting these lines in your code, save the file, delete the Drupal cache, and after that, comment out the appropriate line! It's not needed to run all the time, in every page loads!

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init()
 * @see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7
 */
function testModule_init() {
    // after putting this in your file, save it, delete cache, then COMMENT OUT THE FOLLOWING LINE!!! It should only RUN ONCE (it's enough).
    db_query("UPDATE {system} SET weight = 111 WHERE type = 'module' AND name = 'testModule'");
}
```

Comment: hi @Sk8erPeter, I tried you initial code first. But with this version the FB() function still does not load. The alert appears, but loading FB.api fails. When I copy from this code only the FB.api function into console it works fine... So we start the code too early? How to start it later?

Comment: @Nils: I edited my answer, please see the module weight changing method at the end of the post.